# Proper Way to Delete Baggage JDBC Creates?

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

I'm writing a Java program which traverses everything beneath the user supplied directory looking for h2 databases and displaying their content. Here's the code I've written so far:

```
private void openDatabase(File file) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection connection;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
            DatabaseMetaData md = connection.getMetaData();
            ResultSet resultSet = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println("TABLE: " + resultSet.getString(3));
            }
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It does fine - it finds the `(db)` and prints out the tables in it. Just one problem. Each time it finds the `(db)`, it creates `(db).h2.db` and `(db).trace.db`. This means that on subsequent runs of my program, it finds and scans those in addition to `(db)`. That wouldn't be a big deal, except for the fact that on the third run, it creates `(db).h2.db.h2.db`, `(db).trace.db.h2.db`, `(db).h2.db.trace.db`, and `(db).trace.db.trace.db`. And so on. It's a problem that grows exponentially.

What am I doing incorrectly? How can I either prevent it from producing these extra files entirely or make it clean up after itself when it's done?

Comment: Weird. I guess you can just filter out anything with ".h2." or ".trace."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the H2 database engine, the JDBC URL `jdbc:h2:/directory/test` means the database contents are stored in the file `/directory/test.h2.db`. That means, the database URL does exactly match the file name.

So what you could do is, instead of using the file name directly, use:

```
String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();
if (!fileName.endsWith(".h2.db")) {
    // not a H2 database
    return;
}
String databaseName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length() - ".h2.db".length());
String url = "jdbc:h2:" + databaseName;
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved other problems I was having that I hadn't mentioned to, like the fact SQL statements were failing to find tables that I knew were in the db. I suspect it was producing the new db and then running the statements on those. Just one small part of the question that wasn't answered - how can I prevent it from making the trace file? This is just a small diagnostics program that extracts a few IDs and names from the db, it doesn't need to perform any joins or anything else, so I don't think I need/want a trace file.

Comment: Trace file: What does it contain? It should only be created if there is an exception or other problem.

Comment: I don't know how to check it, but I found this documentation on the trace feature: http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#trace_options

Comment: I added an answer to cover what you missed. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20146342/901641

Answer (score 1):

[Thomas Mueller's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20115069/901641) helped with cleaning up most of the extra files, but one thing he left off was how to clean up the trace files. I found [some documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#trace_options) that explained how to get rid of those files.

You can insert options into the connection URL, separated by semicolons. They take the form option_key=option_value. Two of the option keys are `TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT` and `TRACE_LEVEL_FILE`. Each of them can be set to 0 (off), 1 (error), 2 (info), or 3 (debug).

Here's an except of the code I wrote using the options to properly open the database, without making extra .h2.db files, without a trace file being produced, and with info going into the system log:

```
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
String url = "jdbc:h2:" + path.substring(0, path.length()-6); // jdbc:h2 doesn't like file extensions in the path - remove the .h2.db
String options = ";TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=0;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=2"; // put info on the console, not in a log file
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url + options);
```